# How to select a checkbox by its id and call setChecked?

Tags: vue.js, mocha.js, karma-runner, element-ui

I'm writing a unit test to check that a method is called when a checkbox is clicked.

I'm using ElementUI and here is an extract from the component template:

```
<template lang="pug">
  el-card
    el-checkbox#checkAllCheckbox(
          :indeterminate="isCheckAllIndeterminate"
          v-model="checkAll"
          @change="handleCheckAllChange"
        ) {{ $t('check all') }}
</template>
```

And here is my test:

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import ElementUI from 'element-ui'
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuex)
localVue.use(ElementUI)

 it.only('Should check all', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, { localVue })
        let checkAllCheckbox = wrapper.find('#checkAllCheckbox')
        checkAllCheckbox.setChecked()
      })
})
```

The test fails with then following error:

```
wrapper.setChecked() cannot be called on this element
```

How can I select the checkbox by its id and trigger the change event with the wrapper?

**EDIT**
Following @tao recommendations, I tried using `mount` instead of `shallowMount` in order to avoid stubbing the `ElCheckbox` component:

```
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import ElementUI from 'element-ui'
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuex)
localVue.use(ElementUI)

 it.only('Should check all', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, { localVue })
        let checkAllCheckbox = wrapper.find('#checkAllCheckbox')
        checkAllCheckbox.setChecked()
      })
})
```

But I still get the same error: `wrapper.setChecked() cannot be called on this element`. I also tried importing the `ElCheckbox` component and use it as a stub:

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import ElementUI from 'element-ui'
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent'
import ElCheckbox from 'element-ui/lib/checkbox'  

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuex)
localVue.use(ElementUI)

 it.only('Should check all', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, { localVue, stubs: {
        'el-checkbox': ElCheckbox
      }})
        let checkAllCheckbox = wrapper.find('#checkAllCheckbox')
        checkAllCheckbox.setChecked()
      })
})
```

But still got the same error: `wrapper.setChecked() cannot be called on this element`.

After checking the resulting HTML as suggested, here is what it looks like:

```
<label id="checkAllCheckbox" class="el-checkbox is-checked" aria-controls="undefined">
    <span class="el-checkbox__input is-checked"><span class="el-checkbox__inner"></span>
    <input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="false" class="el-checkbox__original" value=""></span>
    <span class="el-checkbox__label">Check all<!----></span>
</label>
```

ElementUI doesn't attribute the id to the checkbox itself but to the enclosing `label`. So I ended up using `wrapper.find('#checkAllCheckbox input[type="checkbox"]')` and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shallowmount` is a declaration: in this test I nor need neither want any of the subcomponents rendered. They can be safely replaced with a stub and they're irrelevant as far as this test is concerned.

Which means `<el-checkbox>` is replaced by an empty `<el-checkbox-stub>` and so are all the other sub-components in your template. But you can't call `.setChecked()` on a stub. You can only call it on an `<input type="checkbox">`.

One way to fix this would be to replace `shallowMount` in this test with `mount`, which would render `<el-checkbox>`'s markup properly.

Another way to fix it is to tell VueTestUtils not to stub this particular component, by using [stubs](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#stubs). (To be exact, you're not telling it not to stub, you're telling it to stub it using something - it's just that the "something" is the actual component - all other sub-components will still be stubbed). Obviously, you'd have to import `elCheckbox` from the library and specify it in the `shallowMount`'s `stubs` option, as shown in documentation.

Comment: I tried with `mount` but still get the same error (I imported ElementUI: `import ElementUI from 'element-ui'` and made `localVue` use it: `localVue.use(ElementUI)` though). I am trying to import the `ElCheckbox` component to use it as a stub but I am unable to import it properly: I tried `import ElCheckbox from 'element-ui'` and `import ElCheckbox from 'element-ui/types'` but both don't work

Comment: I can't help you more without an actual [mcve] where I could inspect what's going on. The first step would be to determine what's the actual output of your pug code and make sure your selector actually targets the `<input>` element. You might be able to recreate it on codesanbox.io so I could have a look.

Comment: I managed to import the ElCheckbox component properly: `import ElCheckbox from 'element-ui/lib/checkbox'` and used it as a stub: `const wrapper = shallowMount(AlgorithmFamilySpaces, { 
      localVue,
      stubs: {
        'el-checkbox': ElCheckbox
      } })` but got the same initial error: `wrapper.setChecked() cannot be called on this element  `

Comment: OK I will edit my question and add what I tried.

Comment: In the resulting HTML of your component, is there an `<input type="checkbox">` with an id of `checkAllCheckbox`? From what you're saying, the first element in DOM with that id is not an `input[type="checkbox"]`. Also, make sure you only have one element with this id.

Comment: Well it seems like the resulting html is not as imagined. It appears that Element UI does not attribute the id to the `<input "type=checkbox">`. This is really annoying and would make the tests complicated

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to tell `ElementUI` to assign an id to the checkbox properly

Comment: I tried `let element = wrapper.find('input[type="checkbox"]')` and it works. Although this resolves the problem, I would rather get the elements by their ids in order to make the tests more readable ...

Comment: PS: I kept the imported `ElCheckbox` component as a stub so it works

Comment: You should use `wrapper.find('#checkAllCheckbox input[type="checkbox"]')`.